github-action: class path resource can't be resolved
I've got a spring-boot 3 project which uses a special DataSource configuration  for the tests:
@Configuration
class DatabaseTestConfig extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  DataSource getDataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setName("test")
        .setType(H2)
        .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
        .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
        .continueOnError(true)
        .addScript("/h2/dump.sql")
        .build();
  }
}

At the commandline and IDE it works as expected, but in github-action the dump file can't be found. Total path of the file: src/test/resources/h2/dump.sql
Relevant part of the workflow:
  mvn-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up JDK 17 for x64
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'corretto'
          architecture: x64
          cache: maven
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn verify

Part of the worflow log:
 09:58:10.217 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource - Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false]
09:58:10.611 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG o.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Executing SQL script from class path resource [h2/dump.sql]
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in class path resource [codes/thischwa/dyndrest/DatabaseTestConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception with message: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [h2/dump.sql]

The pom.xml is very long, so I just put the link to the file: https://github.com/th-schwarz/DynDRest/blob/develop/pom.xml
Is there anybody who has a hint for me?

Did you try to explicitly specify the classpath in the Maven command? run: mvn -DtestClasspath=src/test/resources verify (if this doesn't work, could you also share your pm.xml configurations in the question please?)

Thanx @GuiFalourd, it doesn't work. I've added the link to the pom.xml, because Its very long.

We'll need more insights to understand why it's not working. An option could be to use a classpath.txt file with the src/test/resources directory included. And then use the command line mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=classpath.txt before performing the mvn verify command. (you can check the target directory during the process between both commands on github actions).

@GuiFalourd Ive created an extra  branch of the project with the 'old' behaviour. I build the classpath.txt' on github-action, add 'src/test/resources' and run mvn -DtestClasspath=classpath.txt verify`. But it fails already. If you want to have a closer look: https://github.com/th-schwarz/DynDRest/actions/runs/9747706765/job/26901019902#step:7:1

I've no idea why, but if I build my DataSource via spring configuration, the git-action runs as expected.
Here is the relevant part:
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:dyndrest;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: dba

  sql:
    init:
      schema-locations: classpath:h2/dump.sql

If you need a clean database, you should use the following annotation at your test class:
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)

Please let me know, if someone knows why  this is running in github-action, and the ways described in my question not.
